# JavaScript error only on Firefox jQuery.Deferred exception: variablename is undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm getting a weird error only on Firefox. Things working as expected on all other browsers including IE.

The error I'm getting is

> jQuery.Deferred exception: first is undefined

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var customer = {{{json customer}}};
    var first = '';
    var second = '';
    var third = '';
    console.log(customer);

    var customer_id = '{{customer.customer_group_id}}';
    customer_id = customer_id * 1;
    console.log(customer_id);
    if(customer_id == 2 || customer_id == null || customer_id == 0){
        console.log('I am running');
        console.log("1 ->" + document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumbs .breadcrumb')[1]['outerText']);
        var first = document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumbs .breadcrumb')[1]['outerText'];
        first = first.trim();
        console.log("First ::" + first);
    }
});
```

The issue seems to have around the trim function.
It still comes up if I try,

```
var newvariable = first.trim();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re using the non-standard `outerText` property, which Firefox doesn’t support and which [evaluates to the same thing as the `innerText` property when read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/outerText).

```
var first = document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumbs .breadcrumb')[1].innerText;
```

If you don’t need to support older browsers, [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is probably preferable because of its more straightforward behaviour.

```
var first = document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumbs .breadcrumb')[1].textContent;
```

If you do, jQuery can fill in:

```
var first = $('.breadcrumbs .breadcrumb').eq(1).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

`outerText` isn't a standard property.  Use `.innerText` instead.

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/outerText